# Package not found but its there

Tags: intellij-idea

```
import org.flarrison.scripts.flarrifarm.tasks.livid.DetectLivid;
```

I'm getting a Package not found error. It doesn't show up as error before i compile. I used the auto completion for it to import. I even clicked CTR-Z until i got back to where the script did run. But it's not now and i have no clue what to do.

Is there any way to get it to recognize it's there? Because it definitely is.

Its telling me that the package "livid" isn't there. BUT IT IS!

Comment: Did you add the library as a reference in project properties? see this http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/how-to-add-a-project-reference-an-introduction-to-intellij-idea-9-for-visual-studio-users/

Comment: Are you using library-based IntelliJ project, or maven?

Comment: It started working maybe it was just a glitch.. i dont know wtf was up